# PyQt: How to 'global' a def in one class for other classes?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 App there are many classes/windows. Almost all of the windows contain one same `def`, which is the `def center(self)` shown in the following code. It has the function to place the windwo in the middle of the screen.

Because they are all same, I would like to ask if there is any method to write this `def` only once, and make it as `global`, as I could imagine, so that other classes/windows may use it?

```
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # some definations
        # click a button to open Window1

    def center(self):  # I have a def here.
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

class Window1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # some definations
    def center(self):  
      # Question: Same def here. How to NOT write this def, but use the def from the MyApp class?
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is not "a def", but a method.

The way to share methods - or any attributes - between classes is not by making them global, but by creating a shared superclass that they can inherit from. So you could do:

```
class CenteredWidget(QWidget):
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

class MyApp(CenteredWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # some definations
        # click a button to open Window1

class Window1(CenteredWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # some definations
```

Since both MyApp and Window1 inherit from CenteredWidget, they both automatically get access to the `center` method it defines.

Answer (score 1):

Use a mix-in class, if there isn't another base class where you can suitablely define `center`.

```
class Centerable(object):
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

class MyApp(QWidget, Centerable):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

class Window1(QWidget, Centerable):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```